# how to backup contacts or sms to SD card as .xml file or .csv file and restore it later

Tags: java, android, sms, backup, contacts

I am trying to develop a feature into my app to backup sms and contacts to SD Card as .xml or .csv format and restore it later.

so please anyone give me some suggestions or some sample code or any resource links related to this.

thanks in advance

Comment: mmh since you write the backup util yourself you should know yourself what it is actually backing up.

Comment: @peter can u give me some tutorials url related to my post

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=android+api+file+system

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    public ArrayList<String> smsBuffer = new ArrayList<String>();
    String smsFile = "SMS"+".csv";
       private void  backupSMS(){
    smsBuffer.clear();
    Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(
            mSmsinboxQueryUri,
            new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date",
                    "body", "type" }, null, null, null);
    //startManagingCursor(cursor1);
    String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body",
            "type" };
    if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
        String count = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
        Log.d("Count",count);
        while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {

             String messageId = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                    .getColumnIndex(columns[0]));

             String threadId = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                    .getColumnIndex(columns[1]));

            String address = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                    .getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
            String name = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                    .getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
            String date = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                    .getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
            String msg = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                    .getColumnIndex(columns[5]));
            String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                    .getColumnIndex(columns[6]));



            smsBuffer.add(messageId + ","+ threadId+ ","+ address + "," + name + "," + date + " ," + msg + " ,"
                    + type);

        }           
        generateCSVFileForSMS(smsBuffer);
    }               
}


 private void generateCSVFileForSMS(ArrayList<String> list)
{

    try 
    {
        String storage_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + smsFile;
        FileWriter write = new FileWriter(storage_path);

        write.append("messageId, threadId, Address, Name, Date, msg, type");
        write.append('\n');

        for (String s : list)
        {
            write.append(s);
            write.append('\n');
        }
        write.flush();
        write.close();
    }

    catch (NullPointerException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Nullpointer Exception "+e);
         //  e.printStackTrace();
     }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }

}
```

Comment: But How to restore sms from csv file ?

Comment: How can I check backup sms.cvs file in my sd cards. I can not find any csv  file in my sd card after execute the above code. please help me to find the backup file.