# Unable to restore .csv for sms in android

Tags: java, android, sms, backup

I found this link to back up sms threads with the code given here [store csv file for sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739034/how-to-backup-contacts-or-sms-to-sd-card-as-xml-file-or-csv-file-and-restore-i) but did not find a solution for restoring it back. I tried to use contentprovider to store back each and every value that I am backing up but Could not find it appropriate as its like showing a new incoming message in inbox. Also this type of restoring was not working well. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have u got solution ?