# Export contacts as vcf file android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build an app that exports and restores the contacts as a vcf file. I found some code around such as

[how to backup contacts or sms to SD card as .xml file or .csv file and restore it later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739034/how-to-)        backup-contacts-or-sms-to-sd-card-as-xml-file-or-csv-file-and-restore-i

[Export the Contacts as VCF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147563/export-the-contacts-as-vcf-file)

But nothing works i get all sorts of errors.
Can anyone please share a working code?
Please do not mark as duplicate i am aware that it has been discussed here but the codes are not working

Comment: Please review the answer is already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739034/how-to-backup-contacts-or-sms-to-sd-card-as-xml-file-or-csv-file-and-restore-i?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Please check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582643/how-to-create-one-vcf-file-for-all-the-contact-in-android?rq=1

Comment: @MIKE Is it working form above two links ?  I have faced same situation as in your question.